# jms server weblogic

Tags: jms

In a recent interview, I was asked what JMS server were you using?I replied...we were using JMS server that ships with weblogic 9.x.
Is there a name for the server?I gather it is not ActiveMQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's the [BEA implementation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/jms/fund.html) of the JMS standard.  They aren't using ActiveMQ.